# No module named srv

Tags: ros, tutorial, beginner-tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was following the tutorial WrittingServiceClient(Python). I have typed the code as it is. The project "makes" properly also, but when I try to rosrun the server or the client the following error shows:

from beginner_tutorials import *
ImportError: No module named srv

Where am I going wrong? How to create the module srv?

N.B.: I have followed the tutorial "Creating a ROS msg and srv" and the srv file exists inside the beginner_tutorials/srv

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52790/no-module-named-srv/) by [dptsrk](https://answers.ros.org/users/3957/dptsrk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 140 on 2013-01-19

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mmodetb](https://answers.ros.org/users/21764/mmodetb/) on 2015-03-07**:
Did you sort it out? I am having exactly the same problem...

**Comment by [dkurzaj](https://answers.ros.org/users/27273/dkurzaj/) on 2016-07-27**:
I encounter the same problem right now, has anybody found why it happens ?

**Comment by [mneumann](https://answers.ros.org/users/37505/mneumann/) on 2018-09-14**:
In my case, I had to `source` the `devel/setup.bash` in each instance of the console I was calling the scripts from. Once for the client, once for the server. Then, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had this error because of module name conflict.

e.g.:

```
catkin_ws/
  | src/
    | package/
      | srv/
        | service.srv
      | scripts
        | package.py
        | code_using_service.py
```

I was importing the service into the `code_using_service.py` file and got the error message:

```
from package.srv import *
ImportError: No module named srv
```

It was looking for the srv module inside my `package.py` module instead of inside my `package/` module. So I just renamed my script file to `package_node.py` to avoid the conflict.

---

Originally posted by [dkurzaj](https://answers.ros.org/users/27273/dkurzaj/) with karma: 126 on 2016-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 11

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vschmidt](https://answers.ros.org/users/25950/vschmidt/) on 2017-01-31**:
This was my problem. To fix it I had to not only rename the script, but also make sure any `pyc` files were removed.

**Comment by [Jägermeister](https://answers.ros.org/users/4624/j%C3%A4germeister/) on 2019-07-29**:
Service name and package name can be the same, right?

**Comment by [traemand](https://answers.ros.org/users/64161/traemand/) on 2021-04-06**:
This solved it for me. I had a .py file named the same as the package name, which then made the script try to import the python file, and not the .srv file from the /srv folder. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the tutorial [Writing a Simple Service and Client (Python)](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient%28python%29), do [Build your nodes](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient%28python%29#rospy_tutorials.2BAC8-Tutorials.2BAC8-WritingServiceClient.Building_your_nodes) section and `rosrun` again. It seems to me you might not have generated `*.srv` modules. In that tutorial page, don't forget to choose your build system (if you're using `rosmake`, choose `rosbuild`).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-01-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The module srv is a python module, which in practice just means a folder named srv with a **init**.py in it. This file is generated from .srv files you define, when building the project correctly.

With catkin, the safest way to rebuild everything is to delete your build and devel folders and rebuild everything.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-01-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jägermeister](https://answers.ros.org/users/4624/j%C3%A4germeister/) on 2019-08-05**:
I don't think this is an answer. You can remove those folders and rebuild everything, there is no guarantee that it will work. One has to check CMakeLists.txt, package.xml and the code files, all should be consistent with the package name and all that.